# How to change a variable based on a discord message?

Tags: javascript, variables, discord, discord.js

I am working on a discord bot, and I am trying to change variables based on user input. The code should function a little bit like this:

```
const w = "something";
const r = "something else";
var a1 = w;

execute(message, args){
    if (!args.length){
        message.channel.send("no arguments");
    } else {
        var args[0] = args[1];
    }
}
```

What I want to happen is that when a user in discord types

```
!command a1 r
```

that the variable a1 changes to "something else". How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object`/`Map` here, instead of variables

Something like:

```
const consts = {
  w: "something",
  r: "something else"
};

const variables = {
  a1: consts.w
};

execute(message, args){
    if (!args.length){
        message.channel.send("no arguments");
    } else {
        variables[args[0]] = consts[args[1]];
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure what you trying to do its good practice.
Using mutable variables is a big window for bugs, especially if the user can change it.

Comment: I am just using it for a small bot for a small server, and I am also implementing a reset function to get everything back to default so it should not generate any big problems. Thank you for the help!